# Unittest with graphical output without monitor

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have an application and lots of unittests. I have some tests that test the graphical output by generating the output then comparing it with a reference image. The assumption is that tests are run on the same machine with the same screen and settings. So the first assumption is the need of a screen.

Is it possible to "abstract" the use of a screen, kind of mocking a screen ? Could Xvnc be a solution ?

Comment: It's not clear to me why the screen is important for running your tests or interpreting the results. Usually, having a monitor is unimportant. Just redirect the output of the tests to a file through command line, e.g. `runtests > output.txt`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712831/log-unittest-output-to-a-text-file). Is this a GUI application with functional tests? In which case, you may be looking for xvfb -- a virtual screen buffer program.

Comment: If you do in fact need the virtual screen for your tests, [pyvirtualdisplay](https://github.com/ponty/pyvirtualdisplay) is a python wrapper for xvfb and supports screen shots. Should be simple to integrate. Have used with success for testing in headless environments for applications that require a screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It is indeed a GUI application ("graphical output")